# Can the input function be used to pass an argument to a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, user-input

First time posting here. New to Python and experimenting to try and better understand recursion and the input function. In this code, I'm trying to take user input **(x)** and pass it to a recursive function. I think it will print a list of **(x)** numbers, where the difference in each successive number reduces by 1. Whatever it does, I will learn from but I really just want to know what I need to change to take user input and pass it to this recursive function. The code was inspired by this example:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_recursion

Thanks.

```
x = int(input("Choose a number "))

def add_last(x):
  result = x + (add_last(x- 1))
  print(result)

add_last(x)
```

Comment: So you want to know what this code does?

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried?

Comment: Hi. No, just how to make it run and print a list of x numbers (defined by the user input) that print the sequence defined by the recursive statement.

Comment: I get this error msg : RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Answer (score 1):

Recursive functions must always have an “end” case, i.e, when to end the recursion?

So in `add_last`, probably add something like:

```
if x==0:
   return 0
```

Without an end case you will likely run into a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

> I think it will print a list of (x) numbers, where the difference in each successive number reduces by 1.

Well, no. In your function you are simply adding integers, more specifically adding the sum of all previous integers, to the current one. So the return value of your function would simply be another integer, specifically the [sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma) of `x`.

EDIT:

Since you are not returning anything, by default the function returns `None`. Therefore the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' for the function definition`.

You need to return an integer to make it work.

EDIT 2:

If you are working with huge numbers, and might need to recur multiple times, as @CoderTang suggested you could use `sys.setrecursionlimit(you_new_limit)`, to set your own recursion limit.

Comment: you could use `sys.setrecursionlimit` if there was a number bigger than 1000

Comment: Oh yes. Forgot the base case. Made the edit. Now it gives a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' for the function definition. And a type error for the last line.

Comment: @Sean-Lee The add_last function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @CoderTang I've edited the post and linked the code example that inspired this experimentation. That one works.

Comment: @Sean-Lee Try visualizing it https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20tri_recursion%28k%29%3A%0A%20%20if%28k%20%3E%200%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20k%20%2B%20tri_recursion%28k%20-%201%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28result%29%0A%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%200%0A%20%20return%20result%0A%0Aprint%28%22%5Cn%5CnRecursion%20Example%20Results%22%29%0Atri_recursion%286%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=44&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: @CoderTang Okay, thanks. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just printing, you don't need to return anything.

```
def add_last(x):
    if x == 0:
        return
    print(x)
    add_last(x-1)

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
add_last(6)
```

Comment: Okay, that's useful to know. Thanks. But now how can I take user input to be the function argument?

Comment: Just call the function with the user input @Sean-Lee.

 ```add_last(int(input(“Enter number:  “)))```

Comment: @AV_69 Okay, thanks. Trying now!

Comment: @AV_69 Was excited it was gonna work but that line gives back a SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier.

Comment: My bad on that, SO changed the quotes to a stylish one. But you get the idea, just get the user input beforehand and pass it in to the function.

Comment: @AV_69 Thanks. Input as the argument to function works! The recursive part still causes errors but this is a separate issue to my question. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @Sean-Lee Sorry for the late response. Does it still cause the same error?